# is servletRequest.setAttribute threadsafe within doFilter()?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, thread-safety

My filter's doFilter does this after validating a user-

```
servletRequest.setAttribute("user", "someUserName");
```

I've a controller like this-

```
@Controller
public class SomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/someURI", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String someMethod(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        String name = httpServletRequest.getAttribute("user").toString();
        System.out.println(name);
        return "hello!";
    }
}
```

My question is - is it guaranteed that the thread which processed `doFilter()` where I set the `user` will be the same thread which is going to call `someMethod`? In other words, is there a security risk here? I am concerned that if there is a thread safety bug, the following line -

```
httpServletRequest.getAttribute("user")
```

might return an incorrect result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Servlet `request` and `response` objects are created afresh for every new `request` and `response` and so by their nature they are thread safe. 
In your code above the filter is called for every `request`, and since the `doFilter` is using the `response object` (it's is thread safe) to fulfill it's objective, the filter is thread safe too.